# How to create Android Handler in a Java plugin called from Unity

Tags: java, android, plugins, handler, unity-game-engine

So, let's say you have a Unity Java plugin, you call into the Java plugin like so

```
private static readonly AndroidJavaClass m_somePlugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.Plugin.blah.SomePlugin");

using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
    using (var currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
    {
        m_somePlugin.CallStatic("onInitialise", currentActivity);
    }
}
```

and the plugin looks something like this

```
public class SomePlugin 
{
    static public void onInitialise(final Activity currentActivity) 
    {
        Handler someHandler = new Handler();
    }
}
```

All quite simple.  Except it will crash.  Creating a Handler is the cause.  I'm guessing it's a thread issue.

So the question is, how does one create a handler in a Java plugin, in the activity that I'm passing in?  Anyone know?

Comment: looks like currentActivity.runOnUiThread may be the way to go.  I'll try it and report on here if it is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution to the problem was to use runOnUiThread.  So in order to get the above code to not crash SomePlugin should look like so

```
public class SomePlugin 
{
    static public void onInitialise(final Activity currentActivity) 
    {
        currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            Handler someHandler = new Handler(); });
    }
}
```